# how to open a modal if an email sucessfully sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, modal-dialog

i was tryin to display or show a modal if email successfully sent or if something else happen while submiting a form, but no luck at all, ive tried many ways but nothing..  ive tried many things but none work, last one i tried was to call it from the php after it confirm that email was sent but when i do that with this code

```
echo "<script>
     $(window).load(function(){
         $('#mymodal').modal('show');
     });
</script>";
```

it says that the $ isnt defined :'( i dont know what else to do

like this it doesnt do what i want it to do. (snippet test)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
        $("#mymodal").modal({backdrop: "static"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn3">click me</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;"> <h4 class="mh4"> Hey there! </h4>
       </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
         <p align=justify>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
        $("#mymodal").modal({backdrop: "static"});
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet works. Whats the problem?

Comment: the problem is that when i try to show the modal once the email is sent it wont show, and it drops an error sayin that $ is not defined, i just want to show the modal to let the user know that i received the msg .. i just dont want to show the msg as an alert() XD

Comment: more like idk how to make it work, (the manual call of the modal)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the modal is considered a separate window so you are trying to transfer variables to a different window, which would result in your undefined error. You need to execute whatever code before the modal closes. Or use a push service.
I would do an ajax POST to your server and then with that response update the page. xmlhttprequest

Comment: i just want to load the modal i mean to show it, i dont want to put any data inside at least nothing like vars, just text something like "thx for contacting me"

Answer (score 0):

You are including **Jquery Version3** https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

while Bootstrap 3 is Supporting Jquery version gretter than 1.9.0 but less than 3.0.x
You can check this error in your browser console. So, try it with including jquery either 1.9.1 or better 2.2.4 will be a good option.

**You may try this to get data from your PHP Script**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn3" onclick="DoYourAction()">click me</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;"> <h4 class="mh4"> Hey there! </h4>
       </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
         <p align=justify>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<script>
function DoYourAction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        /* Your URL from which you are getting data */
        data: { /* Put your parameers that you are sending to the Action */
            "param1": 'valueForparam1',
            'param2': 'valueForparam1'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            /*
             * On Success Show your modal
             */
           $('#mymodal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (errors) {
            /*
             * If Error arrived, you may see in your browser console!
             */
            console.log(errors);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx for the answer, i alrdy added a lower versión(1.12.3) and it says "server understood what u want but wont do it" XD idk rly... this is driving me crazy.. maybe the alert() option isnt a bad idea in the end :'(

Comment: any idea about how to call the function in the php right after the if == true? i think thats what im missing.. :'( i tried putting that echo "<script>$("#myModal").modal("show");</script>"; but it doesnt work

Comment: so u actually know how to fix it? or how to make it work?

Comment: using Ajax will be easy and manageable than echoing java script as string from PHP.

Comment: Is there any way that u could help me with that?

Comment: can i ask where did you write it? i dont see it :x sorry to bother and thx a lot for the help

Comment: I edited my answer, I cant write code in comment. check the snippet i have mentioned in my answer. I have edited for you. also if it is correct accept it as answer